# Correctness of the usage of the phrase 'by (or in) virtue of'

Tags: phrases

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? Are there any alterations I must make?

> I am very much observant **in virtue of** my tendency of being silent.

Comment: It's hard to say whether it's grammatical or not - it's an extremely unnatural way of saying something like "I'm very observant because I'm rather quiet."

Comment: @curiousdannii Thank you very much! Someone has already down-voted my question.  May be because it is worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno... It makes sense to me.  Although It seems like you may be confusing "***by*** *virtue of*," and "***in*** *light of*" - which can both be used in this sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to reply!   It makes complete sense now.